# font smoothing CSS - but for windows?

Tags: css, fonts, font-smoothing

The following code makes my text look so much prettier on Mac:

```
html, body {
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

But it doesn't work on Windows. Is there anything that works the same way for Windows?

Comment: you can try this: html {

text-rendering: optimizeLegibility !important;

-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased !important;

}

Comment: this feels like the kind of thing a casual googling would have given you the answer for. Did you try that? What suggestions did you find that didn't work?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans a bit of casual googling will tell you that this is still a big problem and there is a lot of old useless fixes around on the web.

Comment: if you'd already searched around, it's pretty important to point that out in your question - others looking at your question will only be able to tell how much you already know about your problem based on what you explain in your post, so in this case it would have been good to mention what you already searched for, found, and whether/why that doesn't work. If you leave it off, you get comments like mine, telling you to do a bit of homework first, even if you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Font smoothing is not a standard and there is no guarantee it will work for all of your users. You also have ClearType on Windows that handles the crisp font in at least Internet Explorer.

If you insist on using this you can see browser compatability [here](http://caniuse.com/#search=font-smooth).

Also it should work in Chrome with this:

```
-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Just noticed: antialiased fonts, especially light and thin, look terrible in Chrome on Windows. Perfect on Mac and iOS, though.

Comment: Having the same issue @RishatMuhametshin . Anyone find a work around here?